# Show "Documents/index.cshtml" in the visual studio document well instead of "index.cshtml"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

[image]

I want the tabs to show "documents/index.cshtml", "account/index.cshtml", ... so that I can see which index.cshtml I'm about to click.

Is there a way to do this?

Note: I have the latest resharper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486062/display-folder-name-in-visual-studio-open-file-tab

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate indeed.
I wonder who pays 50 bucks to deal with this..

Comment: Completely agree. Seems daft not to have this functionality built-in.